# IE 6-10 не видят css

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Такая ситуация - http://www.tetrapolis.ru/ - отражается нормально только в IE 11 в остальных он просто не видит не картинок и блоков, вообще ничего, как буд то css воробще нет, подскажите в чём может быть причина (смотрю через данный сервис http://netrenderer.com/ )

Comment: @нгш, это указанный сервис рендерит криво. Указанный сайт более-менее нормально отображается, начиная с IE 8 и хорошо, начиная с IE9. Все стили подключаются нормально.

Comment: а не могли бы вы посоветовать сервис который отражает реальную ситуацию?
PS в 8 ужасно отражается, только что посмотрел

Comment: IETester http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage

Comment: Ответ на мой вопрос 
Использовал CSS Media Queries, из-за этой системы сайт перестаёёт работать в осле